# Can I somehow record the app session on iPad to use it for testing later?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

I'm curious if there is any tools available to record app session in iOS, so later I can use it for testing by running it automatically?!

I used to use this kind of tool in Visual Studio to test my website, I'm wondering if there is anything similar in Xcode.

Comment: do you mean recording javascript events or just a screen recording?

Comment: I meant if for example user starts an app, does tapping, swiping all those...can it be recorded and then played in the app for testing purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I guess my only option here would be to use Automation tool from the Instruments, and just writing javascript code to run my app in a particular way.